# Update a textView in activity from an BaseAdapter

Tags: android

I have an adapter to render values in ListView which extends BaseAdapter.
This adapter gets called in an activity. Activity has an TextView which needs to be updated when an onClickListener is called in Adapter.
Could someone let me know how to update an TextView if a button is clicked in an adapter.
Any examples would be helpful.
thanks.

code

```
private class ViewItem extends Activity{
ImageButton addToCart;
ViewItem(View convertView,final int position)
    {
addToCart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
itemPosition=Integer.parseInt(positionView.getText().toString());
                    int qty = Integer.parseInt(quantity.getText().toString());
                    ShoppingCartHelper.setQuantity(itemPosition, qty);
                    ShoppingCartHelper.itemsInTheCart = ShoppingCartHelper.cartMap.size();
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Successfully, Item added to the Cart...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//I need to update a TextView here                      

                    // Close the activity
                    finish();
                }
            });
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: You need to handle onClick event inside adapter class getView() method to update your TextView.

Comment: Do you have button inside every ListView raw?

Comment: @martin yes every ListView row has button.

Comment: So as I've wrote you need to handle onCLick event inside your adapter class getView() method. Please have a look at answers below, you have to declare button inside getView for each raw. Especially have a look at Muraliganesan's answer. Happy coding.

Comment: @Martin but I have inner class ViewItem which extends Activity, so you are specifying to move the code from ViewItem to getView.

Comment: You have to handle this onClick inside getView() because you are inflating the same xml for each row in your ListView. So you need getItem(position), thats the reason you have to do it inside getView(). Have a look at this tutorial there is sth simmilar but with checkbox. That's what you need to do. http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#overview_listactivity

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        EvenViewHolder holdereven;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInfaltor.inflate(R.layout.schedule_adapter_view,
                    null);
            holdereven = new EvenViewHolder();
            holdereven.time = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.time);
            holdereven.title = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.title);
            holdereven.des = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.des);
 holdereven.time.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(
                    ) {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    //Do your stuff
                }
            });
            convertView.setTag(holdereven);

        } else {
            holdereven = (EvenViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
  static class EvenViewHolder {
    TextView time, title, des;

  }
  }
```

Comment: thanks, as what I am saying is this TextView is not in the layout which is inflated, this is outside of the adapter inflated view in the footer which is an include layout.